# You dont have to recompile app-means?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium, selendroid

Appium documentation says-"You don't have to recompile your app or modify it in any way in order to automate it."
What does it mean actually.. Can anybody please explain?

Comment: Is simply means that to use Appium to test your app, you don't have to change anything about your app. Your app will be separate from your test-code.

Comment: If you look at other API's and framework almost all require some libraries to be added. But Appium allows you to test without any library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you don't need to implement a thing in the application code.
While other frameworks need you to implement some stuff inside your code.
Basically, no need to open the project in xcode, just use the .app file to automate the application using appium.